# Show that $F = \{x\in C([0,1]) : \int_0^1 tx(t)dt > 0 \}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

show that in $C([0,1])$ with $d_1$ metric the set $F = \{x\in C([0,1]) :  \int_0^1 tx(t)dt > 0 \}$ is open

What i do is take the complement of $F$ i mean $F^c=\{x\in C([0,1]) :  \int_0^1 tx(t)dt \leq 0  \}$, and i take $x\in \overline{F^c} $ then i take $y\in B_r(x)\cap F^c$ such that $\int_0^1ty(t)dt=0$ so i prove that $\int_0^1tx(t)dt=0$ then $x \in F^c$ then $\overline{F^c} \subset F^c$ and we know that $F^c\subset \overline{F^c}$ so $F^c$ is closed then $F$ is open, is right?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Where did you use your $r$?

Answer (score 3):

The map $L: C([0,1]) \to \Bbb R$ given by $$L(x) = \int_0^1 tx(t) dt$$

is a linear functional, and it's bounded because for all $x$,

$$|L(x)| \le \left(\int_0^1 t dt \right) \|x\|_{\infty} = \dfrac12 \|x\|_{\infty}$$

Hence, $L$ is continuous. Now $F = L^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is the continuous inverse image of an open set, so it's itself open.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by definition.

I assume that $d_1$ is the standard metric of uniform convergence. Consider some $x_0\in F$, and open ball $B(x_0,\varepsilon)$, $\varepsilon>0$. We will choose $\varepsilon$ such that $B(x_0,\varepsilon)\subset F$.

Let $y\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)$, then $\forall t\in[0,1]$ $y(t)-x_0(t)>-\varepsilon$ and $$\int\limits_0^1ty(t)dt=\int\limits_0^1t(y(t)-x_0(t))dt+\int\limits_0^1tx_0(t)dt\ge\int\limits_0^1tx_0(t)dt-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>0,$$if we take any $0<\varepsilon<2\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1tx_0(t)dt.$ Thus, $y\in F$.

Perhaps, $d_1$ means integral metric. In this case $$\int\limits_0^1ty(t)dt=\int\limits_0^1t(y(t)-x_0(t))dt+\int\limits_0^1tx_0(t)dt\ge\int\limits_0^1tx_0(t)dt-\left|\int\limits_0^1t(y(t)-x_0(t))dt\right|\ge$$$$\ge\int\limits_0^1tx_0(t)dt-\int\limits_0^1t|y(t)-x_0(t)|dt\ge\int\limits_0^1tx_0(t)dt-\int\limits_0^1|y(t)-x_0(t)|dt>$$$$>\int\limits_0^1tx_0(t)dt-\varepsilon>0,\;0<\varepsilon<\int\limits_0^1tx_0(t)dt.$$